# Order char by post title

Tags: order, array

This is my code:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' =>  'post',
    'orderby' => 'post_title',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'posts_per_page' => 15,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => $taxonomyName,
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => $term->term_id,
            'child' => true
        )
    )
);
```

I want to order descending by title but the result is like:

Season 1
Season 10
Season 2
Season 3

And I don't know how to get the result like:
Season 1
Season 2
...
Season 9
Season 10

Comment: so you want to order by post title length and post title together?

Comment: *And I don't know how to get the result like: Season 1 Season 2 ... Season 9 Season 10* - it'll do the thing: `'orderby' => 'title',  'order' => 'ASC'`. [consult Codex first](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters)

Comment: Your questions is a duplicate of [this somewhat old one](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/143680/21376). Short answer, that is ***correct*** alpha numeric ordering. To order the way you want you are in for some difficulty.

Comment: @birgire's suggestion is a good simple way, see also http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/174739/57034 (the new answer bit) for a complex way to do it (patent pending).